# Where can I find a shapefile for the coastline of North America?

Tags: shapefile, data, administrative-boundaries

I am looking for a shapefile representing the coastlines of North America, such as something like this:
http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I'm glad you asked this, as I have been needing to research this for a project and you got me motivated!

Comment: At that point, you should pick one of the answers

Answer (score 6):

**Cloudmade** have the US coastline in [Open Street Map](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Main_Page) in [shapefile format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile) - coastline included.

There is no quick way to extract Coastline from Open Street Map currently so you will have to download the entire data-set and extract what you want.

update 16th December 2015 (due to services discontinued)
Coastline is available from:
http://openstreetmapdata.com/data/coast

Comment: The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

Comment: @AndreyMaraev updated post (the original post was August2011) cloud made discontinued the service, have updated with a new source that will be helpful

Answer (score 6):

For the US - What about the [NOAA Shoreline site](http://shoreline.noaa.gov/)? Specifically the [Coastal Geospatial Data Project](http://coastalgeospatial.noaa.gov/data_gis.html).

EDIT: [NOAA National Geophysical Data Center GSHHS Dataset](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/shorelines/gshhs.html) does cover the whole world. And here are some other sources at [marinegis.com](http://www.marinegis.com/dataen.html)

Comment: I was just looking (and it wasn't clear to me as I'm unfamiliar with the data); does this include Canada also?

Comment: @celenius - see edits, and thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

The reference coastline data that [OSM](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) uses (at different scales) might be useful:

http://tile.openstreetmap.org/world_boundaries-spherical.tgz # (50M)
http://tile.openstreetmap.org/processed_p.tar.bz2 # (227MB)
http://tile.openstreetmap.org/shoreline_300.tar.bz2 # (46MB)

The `processed_p` shapefile is the highest-detail coastline data for the entire world, but it's not divided by country. You might be able to take that data and extract just the data for North America.

Comment: I look for something like that, highly detailed for North America

Comment: Take the whole world from http://openstreetmapdata.com/data/coastlines and clip it to the area of your needs using QGIS or any other GIS software. Please select one answer as accepted by clicking on the white icon to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work reasonably well, and the larger site has different resolutions available. Data as shapefile.  [Natural Earth Data](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/)

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

> TIGER = Topologically Integrated Geographic Encoding and Referencing
>   TIGER products are spatial extracts from the Census Bureau's MAF/TIGER
>   database, containing features such as roads, railroads, rivers, as
>   well as legal and statistical geographic areas. The Census Bureau
>   offers several file types and an online mapping application

[Census Data](http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger.html)

Comment: The Census department created Tiger files from 1:100,000-scale Digital Line work, National Mapping Accuracy requirements allow it to have an error of +/- 167 feet.  This creates displacement errors that can be eliminated with better sources. Not to mention the bureaucracy that prevents errors from being fixed.