# Why don't shapefiles online contain the coastline (country borders)?

Tags: shapefile, data, vector, cartography

I have searched everywhere and Geofabric has the best packages of shps yet doesn't have the coastline of countries.

I'm talking about the line that demarcates a country i suppose they are called borders.
Diva's site : I have no clue about its archives.

question 1

About the  http://openstreetmapdata.com/data/coastlines should i download the coastline at international level and then crop out with a gis software the country that i want?

question 2

Is there a site that has the borders for each country seperately in a good archive with the roads,railways etc

Thnks

Comment: See: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/13285/1872

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Are you making a distinction between coastlines and the borders presented as such in available shapefile, and if so what is it? Are you looking for more detailed lines? Something showing the difference between high and low tides? Please **edit** your question to provide additional detail.

Comment: Duplicate: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142735/polygons-of-countries-including-territorial-waters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this site with OpenStreetMap data:

https://osmdata.openstreetmap.de/

Or even Natural Earth data has coastlines:

http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-physical-vectors/

Comment: Sure stumbled upon it earlier but didn't get how you choose country.

Comment: About the http://openstreetmapdata.com/data/coastlines should i download the coastline at international level and then crop out with a gis software the country that i want?

Comment: @Jack.Usa I'd think that would work ok! They don't seem to be broken out by Country. Have you also looked at Natural Earth data?  http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-physical-vectors/